# How would I go about creating a grid like this using HTML and CSS is it possible?

Tags: html, css

I've been trawling the internet and found a few ways on how to make tables but I guess what im trying to achieve is a little bit different. Ive seen how you create a board but how would you go about creating squares with different sizes?

[image: Grid created in Illustrator]

Comment: For sake of ease / sanity, I use tools like https://grid.layoutit.com/

Comment: That's mint cheers.

Comment: Doesnt seem to do what I want it to do though unfortunately.